# Is spawning a new object instance for each thread a thread-safe operation?

Tags: java, multithreading

When running multiple threads, I read that interleaving becomes an issue, where one thread doesn't account for the changes of an object by another thread. Jave provides synchronized methods, synchronized states, Lock objects, and the new Concurrency class objects to ensure each thread gets its exclusive turn to affect the object fields before other threads affect them when multiple threads affect a single object.

Now, while this is clear, it gets a little gray for me when you are not working with a single object but using multiple threads for MULTIPLE objects. So I tried to test this. I have an ExecuterService with 50 threads. It spawns a new Responder thread (which is itself is a NEW OBJECT):

```
    ExecutorService executor=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
        executor.execute(new Responder()); 
    }
```

Because each thread is itself an instantiated object, if my Responder class looks like this:

```
public class Responder implements Runnable {
    private ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private Random random = new Random();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            list.add(random.nextInt(100));          
        }
        System.out.println("The list size: " + list.size());
    }

}
```

Does each thread work with its own Responder instance so that thread safety is not an issue? For example, is ArrayList list shared data between threads? My gut feeling says that thread safety is not an issue here because each threads works with its own instance, its own members, and not shared data, and when I tried running this example, the size() call outputs the same (1000) for all the threads. So it seems it is thread safe, but I tried a supposedly unthread safe way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i;
    //checking if instantiating new object into executor is thread safe
    ExecutorService executor=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);
    for(i=0;i<50;i++){
        executor.execute(new Responder()); 
    }
    // checking that running multiple threads with shared object is not thread safe
    UnsafeResponder unsafeResp = new UnsafeResponder();
    unsafeResp.execute();
}

public class UnsafeResponder {
    private ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private Random random = new Random();

    private void processData(){
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            list.add(random.nextInt(100));
        }
    }

    public void execute(){
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                processData();
            }           
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                processData();
            }           
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //print out value of shared data
        System.out.println("The list size of shared data: " + list.size());
    }
}
```

And that unthread safe way correctly printing out 2000 every time I called it even though I am not using locks or synchronized statements. So that is why I am not even 100 percent sure if my initial example has a thread safety issue, since I cannot seem to produce a thread-unsafe equivalent.

Comment: @user2864740 can you rephrase that? I'm not sure how that "executor.execute(new Responder()); " causes a shared mutable state.

Comment: @user2864740 so when I run "executor.execute(new Responder()); ", that means each Responder is working with its own data and thus there could be no issue with thread safety, correct?

Comment: @user2864740 I just read your edited comment. So you are saying that the first example does not have thread safety issues because each thread deals with its own object, whereas the second example can potentially have thread safety issues because they have a shared mutable state. Out of curiosity, I ran that second example 50 times, and it always gave me the right value, which shouldn't be the case if it is broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just because threaded code *appears* to work in a given environment does *not* mean it is *guaranteed* to work.

Threaded coded that is not guaranteed is *not* thread-safe code. Rather, the program must be *reasoned* to be correct by not violating any base guarantees/axioms/rules. General execution of code can only reject an assertion of thread-safety (when it fails), but it cannot not prove thread-safety.

In the first example, where there is no shared mutable state and each task is its *own* object with its *own* independent state (i.e. distinct ArrayList objects), it can be trivially reasoned to be thread-safe. The threads simply don't interact with each others data.

However, it is incorrect to assume the second example is thread-safe because it does not use proper thread-safe access of the shared state/data; in fact, it is *broken* because [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is *not* guaranteed to be thread-safe:

> **Note that [ArrayList] is not synchronized.** *If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally*. (A structural modification is any operation that *adds* or deletes one or more elements..)

The specific example, however, makes this issue harder to detect (at least on x86 systems) due to the use of `Thread.sleep` which in effect ensures the threads do nothing most of the time. For instance, each thread only "adds one item" every several milliseconds - eons to a CPU! - and the chance for negative interactions is reduced.

Here is an example which is [more] likely to produce inconsistent results:

```
public class UnsafeResponder implements Runnable {
    private ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private int LIMIT = 1000000; // More operations
    private int THREADS = 10;    // More threads

    public void run()
        // Less delays
        for(int i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++){
            list.add(i);
        }
    }

    public void execute(){
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for (int t = 0; t < THREADS; t++) {
            Thread th = new Thread(this);
            th.start();
            threads.add(th);
        }

        try {
            for (Thread th : threads) {
                th.join();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Test failed!", e);
        }

        System.out.println("Expected: " + (THREADS * LIMIT));
        System.out.println("  Actual: " + list.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: _Just because threaded-code appears to work in a given environment does not mean it is guaranteed to work_. +1

Comment: To improve the example add a `CountDownLatch` at the beginning of the run-method so that all tasks start running at more or less the same time. In the current example the first thread could finish before the last thread is starting (creating and starting threads takes time too).

Comment: I don't understand why everyone says first example is thread-safe. Topic starter creates `ArrayList` on main thread (which creates `Responder`s) and then `ArrayList` is used by spawned threads. Shared state (`ArrayList`) does exist. It may work correct only because at a point of time threads created they don't have cache. But threads a actually reused because of `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`. Can somebody please explain where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the second example both threads are referencing the same list with no synchronization, which is not thread-safe. In fact, running this example on my old laptop (using JDK1.6 on Windows 7 with Intel Core 2 Duo CPU) does not show the same result. Sometimes it shows the final size of the list as 2000, but other times 1999, or even 1992 in one case. I also tried to let the second thread remove from the list (in case it is not empty) instead of adding and it also gives inconsistent results.

```
private void processData2(){
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(!list.isEmpty()) {
            list.remove(0);
        }
    }
}

...

Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        processData();
    }           
});

Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        processData2();
    }           
});
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

This clearly shows it is not thread-safe.

To further confirm, I switched to a synchronized list:

```
private List<Integer> list=Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

and this time running the example always yields a size of 2000.

On the other hand, running the first example always gives a result of 1000 for the size of the list. Each executor task references its own object and its field members.

Comment: I am running Oracle Java 8 and I ran that second example 50+ times and it always gives me 2000.

Comment: I'm using JDK1.6.0_21 32-bit Windows 7 using Intel Core 2 Duo @2.4GHz.

Comment: @JohnMerlino you cannot prove the hypothesis of thread safety through empirical testing. You can only reject it.

Answer (score 0):

**No. It is not.**

If you run a non-thread safe code within a single thread and it is guaranteed that no other thread runs it - then this is "thread safe". This is more or less what synchronize does. So in many cases, creating that new object will be thread safe.

However (now - for a short answer): IN GENERAL THE APPROACH YOU MENTION IS NOT THREAD SAFE! That is "**generating that new object does not guarantee thread safety**".

There is a simple counter example: The class could have a non-thread safe static field which is accessed by each of these "new" objects.

(Actually it will be non-thread safe in many other cases (e.g. the new objects share references to other object or use other non-thread-safe static methods (like accessing a file)).